# My dishwasher smells fishy after running it, like a lake!

Tags: dishwasher

I have a new dishwasher, it's a LG and the problem was happening with my old Bosch also. Even if I clean out the filter, even the first time I ran it - it stinks when I open it after it runs.

It smells like fishy lake water. Could there be something not connected properly, like the garbage disposal or hoses or pipes, that maybe have white algae? Sorry I'm throwing it all out there now :)

Comment: Was it fitted professionally?

Comment: does it smell when you do not use detergent  or glass shiner liquid ?

Comment: Are you sure of the water supply?

Comment: Same problem with two dishwashers, probably not the dishwashers.  Can be what you put into them, something with the plumbing, or the water.  Dishwashers usually heat water up to high temperatures and smells might be more noticeable.

Comment: Can you see any of the drain hose or is it all plumbed in behind the unit? If you can see it (and it's possibly plumbed in under your sink) take a pic or 2 and [EDIT](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/250286/edit) your question to add them in (use the button with "mountains" on it when editing).

Comment: Please [edit] to provide pictures showing the drain connections, which seem likely to be improper.

Answer (score 3):

Old and new dishwasher both stink = improper drain connection.

More detail in the answer might be possible with more detail in the question.